# Redux middleware, thunks?

Tags: javascript, redux

I've taken this straight from the Redux documentation:

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  console.info('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  console.groupEnd(action.type)
  return result
}
```

Now, I know how to use promises, but thunks... I'm slightly lost.

Why do they do the following: `store => next => action =>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the redux documentation about [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html), you can see that the ES6 arrow functions chain:

```
logger = store => next => action =>
```

looks like this when translated to ES5:

```
function logger(store) { // this is not the store, just an object with getState and dispatch
  return function wrapDispatchToAddLogging(next) {
    return function dispatchAndLog(action) {
      console.log('dispatching', action)
      let result = next(action)
      console.log('next state', store.getState())
      return result
    }
  }
}
```

**Why do we need a function that returns a function:**

This is called partial application, and you can read more about it in this [article](http://raganwald.com/2015/04/01/partial-application.html).

The basic idea is that if you need to supply 3 arguments for a function, but you've got only 1 of them now, 1 later, and the 3rd will be in the far future, you can apply the arguments by order whenever they are available, and not at once. Each time you apply an argument, you get a new function, which has the parameter "stored" in it's context.

**In Redux**

The middleware needs partial application because there are several steps in the creation of the [middleware's chain](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js):

**Note:** this is the actual "store" that is passed to the 1st argument:

```
const middlewareAPI = {
  getState: store.getState,
  dispatch: (action) => dispatch(action)
}
```

1. iterate the middleware's array, invoke each function and supply the middlewareAPI to each function (the `store =>` param):

   chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
2. compose the array of middlewares:

   dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)
3. And in [compose](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.js) pass each middleware as the `next =>` parameter to the one before it, and pass the `dispatch` to the last:

   return funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
4. Now the a middleware is a simple function with only one param `action =>`, and whenever an action travels the middleware chain, the `action =>` function of each middleware is invoked with the current action.